# Subscribers with undelivered status - SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to query subscribers who didn't receive a SMS by using the _smsmessagetracking data view.

I am using the following SQL query:

```
Select
Mobile as Celular
From
_smsmessagetracking
Where
MessageText = 'Message text'
and
Sent = 1
and
Undelivered = 1
```

But it doesn't return the mobile numbers that didn't receive the message.

What does the 'Undelivered' field mean? Is it possible to query contacts who didn't receive a message that was sent to them?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out who didn't receive your SMS by quering `_UndeliverableSms` data view. This is detailed in their documentation - [**UndeliveredSMS**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_retrieving_information_on_undelivered_sms_messages_for_mobileconnect.htm&type=5)

Reason can be any of the following :

- Mobile device is powered off
- User is out of range of cellular networks
- Number is for a landline
- Causes not related to Marketing Cloud

As for working with the `_smsmessagetracking` data view, the field `Undelivered` should be a boolean field for records that were indeed ***not*** delivered to. The field `Delivered` should always be of the opposite value here then.